# spark scala DataFrame error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a below data frame in Spark 1.6,  I want to use the filter variable inside the dataframe filter like below but getting error.

```
 val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
 ("None", "a", "b"), ("c", "None", "d"), ("e", "f", "None"), ("g", "h", "i") )).toDF("A", "B", "C")

val  fil =  """($"A" !== "None") && ($"B" !== "None") && ($"C" !== "None")"""
```

When I run this

```
 df.where(fil).show
```

I am getting this error :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.2] failure: identifier expected

    ($"A" !== "None") && ($"B" !== "None") && ($"C" !== "None")
     ^
            at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.SqlParser$.parseExpression(SqlParser.scala:49)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.where(DataFrame.scala:806)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use either proper SQL:

```
val fil =  """A != "None" AND B != "None" AND C != "None""""
```

or DSL (2.x)

```
val fil = ($"A" =!= "None") && ($"B" =!= "None") && ($"C" =!= "None")
```

(1.x):

```
val fil = ($"A" !== "None") && ($"B" !== "None") && ($"C" !== "None")
```

Comment: when i do this val fil = ($"A" =!= "None") && ($"B" =!= "None") && ($"C" =!= "None") fil will be of  org.apache.spark.sql.Column type it works, but when I have a string hwo to convert that to org.apache.spark.sql.Column  so that I can use it in data frame filter. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

This """($"A" !== "None") && ($"B" !== "None") && ($"C" !== "None")""" has been substituted as a string in the Where condition.

You can create sequence of column names and refer those columns in the where condition directly like, 
columns.head !== "None:" in the where condition directly